# How to install mingw in this satuation

Tags: mingw-w64

[the error in the photo[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0npU2.png)
that massage pop up when I try to install mingw-w64 and there is no internet problem
I downloaded it several times but the same problem

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Version 8.1.0 is a bit outdated. There are more recent versions of MinGW-w64.

Try the standalone build from https://winlibs.com/ : it has a much more recent version and requires no installation (just unzip the download).